# Tengo un error en traer el ultimo ID, registrado en una tabla mysql

Tags: php, mysql

me podrian ayudar a resolver esto:

Tengo un problema en traerme el ultimo ID de una tabla en la base de datos.

```
<?php
// 1. Basic connection opening (for MySQL)
$host = 'localhost';
$database = 'sc';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database;charset=utf8";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

// 2. Selected last id field of table customers
$query = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM customers";

$query_success = $pdo->query($query);
echo $query_success;

?>
```

ERROR

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\laragon\www\sc\test.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\sc\test.php on line 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que la razón es porque estás tratando de imprimir un statement del *PDO*.

Tu sentencia `$query_success = $pdo->query($query);` genera una sentencia preparada.
En este caso con `$query_success->fetchColumn();` accedemos al resultado del query.

Por lo que esa parte de tu código quedaría:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM customers";
$query_success = $pdo->query($query);
echo $query_success->fetchColumn();
```

Pero para que sea más legible recomiendo:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM customers";
$stmt = $pdo->query($query);
echo $stmt->fetchColumn();
```